# How to update react components based on websocket messages?

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I'm developing a React component that uses WebSocket for real-time communication. The WebSocket connection is established in a `useEffect` hook with a system ID dependency, `system.id`, which is expected to change infrequently. Here's a simplified version of my component:

```js
export function Playground({ system }) {
  const [nodes, setNodes] = useState(system.nodes);
  const [edges, setEdges] = useState(system.edges);

  useEffect(() => {
    const ws = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:8080/ws/${system.id}`);

    ws.onopen = () => {
      console.log('WebSocket connection opened:', system.id);
    }

    ws.onmessage = (event) => {
      const messageData = JSON.parse(event.data);
      console.log('WebSocket message received:', messageData);

      setNodes((prevNodes) => {
        let newNodes = prevNodes.map(node => {
          if (node.id === messageData.nodeId) {
            return {
              ...node,
              data: {
                ...node.data,
                metrics: messageData.metrics,
              }
            };
          } else {
            return node;
          }
        });

        return newNodes;
      });
    }

    return () => {
      if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        ws.close();
      }
    }
  }, [system.id]);
```

However, I'm currently running into an issue while running React in strict mode. I've noticed that the Playground component gets rendered multiple times. When observing the console, I see "WebSocket connection opened: systemID1" printed twice and then "WebSocket connection opened: systemID2" once.

When the WebSocket messages are received the prevNodes variable in the setNodes updater function seems to have the nodes of systemID1 even after the WebSocket has opened a connection for systemID2. Consequently, updates to the nodes fail.

Can anyone explain why prevNodes retains the old system's nodes even after the WebSocket connection has changed? What am I missing here? How can I ensure that prevNodes reflects the nodes for the current system ID?

Thank you in advance for your help!

The behavior does not take place when strict mode is turned off

Comment: Because the setNodes update is happening asynchronously, you probably will need to have a means of invalidating that update in the cleanup function of the useEffect.  Also, you are not deep-copying the nodes, so when you update them in the for-loop, you are actually mutating your original state.

Comment: @DanielBank I have updated the code to use map instead, but I'm still facing the issue. How would I go about cleaning up a state update?

Comment: I would set a variable at the top of the useEffect, `let isStale = false` and check it inside the setNodes callback, `if(!isStale) { ... }`.  And in the cleanup function I would set `isStale = true`.  Something like that might help